# Aerospike debian compatibility metrics

Tags: aerospike, debian-packaging

On Aerospike docs it is mentioned that AS version [6.0 added support for deb 11](https://download.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#6.0.0.0). does it mean older AS version are not compatible with deb11? Can someone please share compatibility metrics of AS with debian version

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the other answer was removed, it seemed accurate to me.

By “support” it means that we actively test and produce builds for the specific distribution. Older versions would probably compile on newer distros, but it won’t be a combination that we test.

You can find which distributions that we support for a particular release by observing the download options for that release. If the distribution is newer than the release then we couldn’t have tested or built for that release at the time when it was released.